# Tirar una excepción si el numero no esta compredido entre 1 y 12

Tags: python

No se programar este tipo de excepciones, he buscando en otras partes pero sin resultado, aparentemente creo que tienes que crear una clase pero no estoy seguro de ello.

Comment: ¿Cuál número? ¿Cuál es tu código? Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Para lanzar una excepción tienes que hacer `raise Excepción("Mensaje")`, donde `Excepción` ha de ser una clase que herede de `Exception`. Puedes crear tu propia clase para ello (algo tan simple como `class MiExcepcion: pass` ya serviría, una clase vacía), pero normalmente no es necesario, pues puedes elevar una de las muchas que Python tiene predefinidas. Para tu caso parece apropiada la excepción `ValueError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con un `if`:

```
n = 13
if n in range(1, 12):
    raise Exception("{} fuera de rango".format(n))
```

o con `assert`:

```
n = 13
assert(n in range(1, 12))
```

Favor de ser más especifico para poderte proporcionar una respuesta mas concreta.

Comment: perfecto , muchas gracias!